# Jpa Join query with Data from both tables, org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have this structure

VehicleBrand

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class VehicleBrand {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String otherInfo;
}
```

VehicleModel

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class VehicleModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private VehicleBrand brand;

    private String name;

    private String otherInfo;
}
```

I also have Dto objects which i want to use, because i want to get a join query which will return data from both tables,

ModelDto

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ModelDto {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private long brand_id;
}


@Getter
@Setter
public class VehicleBrandModelDto {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    List<ModelDto> model;
}
```

The query i want to execute with jpa is this

select vb.id , vm  from vehicle_brand  vb join vehicle_model vm on vb.id = vm.brand_id group by vb.id, vb, vm , vm.brand_id;

Now i have 1122 records when i execute this on the database. but there are only 85 distinct car brands

The result i am hoping to get is a list of  public class VehicleBrandModelDto {

```
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    List<ModelDto> model;
}
```

where there are 85 brands and inside each object a list of models that belong to that brand.

```
Currently i have tried the following solutions 

@Repository
public class VehicleBrandRepository {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List getSuggestionList() {
        Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select vb.name, vm as model from 
      vehicle_brand  vb join vehicle_model vm on vb.id = vm.brand_id group by vb.name, vm");
        return nativeQuery.getResultList();
    }
//    public List<VehicleBrandModelDto> getSuggestionList() {
//        Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createQuery("select vb.id, vb.name, vm as model from 
         VehicleBrand  vb join VehicleModel vm on vb.id = vm.brand.id group by vb.id, vb.name, vm");
//        return nativeQuery.getResultList();
//    }
}
```

second solution with createQuery gives result of 1122 records which i tried to group using stream api but i had class cast exception  and first query returns the error

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002
```

Any suggestion how i can achieve this or may this is not possible ?

db properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://changed.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/changed
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=false
spring.datasource.username=changed
 spring.datasource.password=changed
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.connection.pool_size=17
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

DB version postgress 12

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: I am using postgres @SternK

Comment: There are a lot of postgre dialects in hibernate? What exactly dialect do you use and what postgres version do you have?

Comment: i have posted by db properties @SternK above

Comment: What postgre database version do you use?

Comment: postgres version 10

Comment: So, try to use `PostgreSQL10Dialect` hibernate dialect.

Comment: sorry its from heroku and its 12

Comment: but thats not the issue im trying to see if i could return a list of VehicleBrandModelDto where each object will contain a list of models

Comment: The `PostgreSQL10Dialect` is the latest hibernate dialect for the Postgres db, so this is a right chose in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you get this `No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002` error. Could you post the whole stacktrace please? This usually suggests that you use a SQL type for which no matching Hibernate type is regsitered in the dialect. The type code 2002 refers to `STRUCT` types, but the model you posted does not contain any exotic types. I guess `VehicleModel` has some other attributes which use a type that isn't registered properly. Could you show the full mapping of `VehicleModel`?

You might also like what [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) has to offer.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(VehicleBrand.class)
public interface VehicleBrandModelDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    // Use this if you have an inverse one-to-many
    @Mapping("models")
    // Otherwise you can also do ad-hoc joins
    // @Mapping("VehicleModel[brand.id = VIEW(id)]")
    List<ModelDto> getModel();

    @EntityView(VehicleModel.class)
    interface ModelDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
        @Mapping("brand.id")
        long getBrandId();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`VehicleBrandModelDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, VehicleBrandModelDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
List<VehicleBrandModelDto> findAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem while i was having particularly the same query (as the one above):
**"select vb.name, vm as model
from
vehicle_brand  vb
join vehicle_model vm
on vb.id = vm.brand_id
group by vb.name, vm "** ,

so from this query you are trying to get the vehicle_brand_name and the vehicle_model object and
the error: "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002" as i understood is thrown when the query is trying to return the vehicle_model object, so the actual dialect you are using cannot map it.
one solution could be to change the query and instead of returning the complete vehicle_model like you are doing : "select vb.name, **vm as model**
from
vehicle_brand  vb
join vehicle_model vm
on vb.id = vm.brand_id
group by vb.name, vm " ,

you change it to : "select vb.name, **vm.name as vehicle_name, vm.other_info as vehicle_other_info**
from
vehicle_brand  vb
join vehicle_model vm
on vb.id = vm.brand_id
group by vb.name, vm ", so the idea is to return the vehicle_model fields one by one and this way you get the vehicle_model result separately and you can create your VehicleModel Object once you will get the result from the query,
hope this solution will help someone.